# Trouble Finding Error Logs in wp-env

Tags: docker, wp-env

New to [wp-env](https://developer.wordpress.org/block-editor/reference-guides/packages/packages-env/), which is mostly a fantastic dev tool.

```
{
  "plugins": ["./blinkwellness-mindbody"],
  "config": {
    "WP_DEBUG": true,
    "WP_DEBUG_LOG": true,
    "WP_DEBUG_DISPLAY": true,
    "SCRIPT_DEBUG": true
  },
  "phpVersion": "8.1",
  "mappings": { "profileApp": "./profileApp" },
  "env": {
    "development": {
      "themes": ["./customtheme"]
    },
    "tests": {
      "config": {
        "KEY_1": false
      },
      "port": 3300
    }
  }
}
```

However, I am having trouble finding error logs. At the moment developing an Ajax feature, which started returning a 500 error.

When running `wp-env logs all`, the result is:

```
...523db7a-tests-wordpress-1  | 172.21.0.1 - - \
[16/Feb/2023:13:23:27 +0000] "POST /wp-admin/admin-ajax.php \
HTTP/1.1" 500 484 "http://localhost:3300/schedule/"  \
"Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 \ 
(KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/109.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
```

Empty content in `/var/log/apache2/error.log`.

Only wordpress debug log I'm finding on the server, `/var/www/html/wp-content/debug.log`, which only has some `PHP Deprecated` and other warnings in it.

Any suggestions?

### UPDATE

Went to another dev approach (Roots/Trellis, virtualbox), which runs Nginx and there indeed the relevant `Fatal Error` is listed in `/var/log/nginx/debug.log`.

Where it gets thrown is:

```
if ( WP_DEBUG ) {
    throw new \Exception( $err->getMessage() );
}
```

So, maybe there's a different php log level between wp-env and the Trellis virtualbox configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I added:

`trigger_error( ini_get('error_log'), E_USER_WARNING );`

which showed:

`/dev/stderr`

Adding to `.wp-env.json`:

```
{
  "config": {
    "WP_DEBUG_LOG": "/var/www/html/wp-content/debug.log"
  },
...
```

seems to work for me.

Running `npx wp-env run cli wp config get WP_DEBUG` should return `1` showing that WP_DEBUG is enabled by default.